# Adding a new item to SharePoint 2010 list using client OM without retrieving the whole list

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

MSDN has this example for adding a new item to a sharepoint list:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;  

namespace Microsoft.SDK.SharePointServices.Samples
{
    class CreateListItem
    {
        static void Main()
        {   
            string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection"; 

            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");  

            ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
            ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
            oListItem["Title"] = "My New Item!";
            oListItem["Body"] = "Hello World!";  

            oListItem.Update();

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();         
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, does this code first retrieves all the items that exist in the list, and then adds the new item?
Or, does it retrieve an empty list, so I can add items to it in an efficient manner?

Thanks,
ashilon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always inspect requests using networking tools like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

In the provided example, *neither list items nor list object are retrieved*, see the comments below:

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle); //get List object reference (note, it is not initialized until requested from the server) 

var itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
var listItem = list.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);   
listItem[propertyName] = propertyValue;
listItem.Update();     //prepare to create new List Item
ctx.ExecuteQuery();   //submit request to the server goes here
```